# What is the fastest way to extract a thumbnail from an image?

Tags: c++, winapi, thumbnails, gdi+

I want to extract a thumbnail from an image, so I tried to use GDI+. What I did was to create a new small `Bitmap` to hold the thumbnail, and using `Graphics::DrawImage()` to draw the bitmap into it (and hence getting a thumbnail).

But when using this approach on a large number of images, it gets really slow. So is there a way to speed it up (by using only Windows API and not an external library).

**Note:** I know that some images store a thumbnail inside of them, but I am looking to extract a thumbnail from the ones that don't.

Comment: You should use threads to make it faster.

Comment: Take a look at this implementation: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/usingimages/article.php/c899/List-Control-displaying-image-thumbnails.htm

Comment: Why do you feel that you can do it faster? What evidence do you have to believe that?

Comment: @David Heffernan Windows Explorer displays the thumbnails very fast when viewing them for the first time (before it creates a cache for them that is).

Comment: I don´t know how large your number of images is, but Windows Explorer (before cache generation) doesn´t generate all thumbnails in the directory, just the ones of the files that are currently visible. If you scroll down, it continues generating for the new visible files. => Windows Explorer hasn´t a large number of files to deal with.

Comment: Do you have any measurements? How about some code, and some data? I have a suspicion that you are optimising before fully understanding whether or not you have identified a bottleneck that can be improved,

Comment: You can try Image::GetThumbnailImage(), it cannot be slower than the expensive rescaling that Graphics::DrawImage() needs to do.  But you'd be wise to take advantage of ShGetFileInfo() to maximize the odds that you get help from Explorer.  And that it will look the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase speed by loading thumbnail from EXIF (for JPEG and some other formats). But `GetThumbnailImage`'s result isn't good. Here is another implementation:

Usage:

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* thumb = GetThumbnail(filename, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
```

Code:

```
PropertyItem* GetPropertyItemFromImage(Gdiplus::Image* bm, PROPID propId) {
    UINT itemSize = bm->GetPropertyItemSize(propId);
    if (!itemSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    PropertyItem* item = reinterpret_cast<PropertyItem*>(malloc(itemSize));
    if (bm->GetPropertyItem(propId, itemSize, item) != Ok) {
        free(item);
        return 0;
    }
    return item;
}

UINT VoidToInt(void* data, unsigned int size) {
    switch (size) {
        case 8:
            return *reinterpret_cast<UINT*>(data);
        case 4:
            return *reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(data);
        case 2:
            return *reinterpret_cast<WORD*>(data);
        default:
            return *reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(data);
    }
}

typedef IStream * (STDAPICALLTYPE *SHCreateMemStreamFuncType)(const BYTE *pInit, UINT cbInit);
SHCreateMemStreamFuncType SHCreateMemStreamFunc = 0;

bool IsVista() {
    static int isVista = -1;
    if (isVista == -1)
    {
        OSVERSIONINFO osver;
        osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);

        isVista = (::GetVersionEx(&osver) &&
            osver.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT &&
            (osver.dwMajorVersion >= 6));
    }
    return isVista != FALSE;
}

Gdiplus::Bitmap* BitmapFromMemory(BYTE* data, unsigned int imageSize) {
    if (WinUtils::IsVista()) {
        if (!SHCreateMemStreamFunc) {
            HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary(_T("Shlwapi.dll"));
            SHCreateMemStreamFunc = reinterpret_cast<SHCreateMemStreamFuncType>(GetProcAddress(lib, "SHCreateMemStream"));
            if (!SHCreateMemStreamFunc) {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        Gdiplus::Bitmap * bitmap;
        IStream* pStream = SHCreateMemStreamFunc(data, imageSize);
        if (pStream) {
            bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pStream);
            pStream->Release();
            if (bitmap) {
                if (bitmap->GetLastStatus() == Gdiplus::Ok) {
                    return bitmap;
                }
                delete bitmap;
            }
        }
    } else {
        HGLOBAL buffer = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, imageSize);
        if (buffer) {
            void* pBuffer = ::GlobalLock(buffer);
            if (pBuffer) {
                Gdiplus::Bitmap * bitmap;
                CopyMemory(pBuffer, data, imageSize);

                IStream* pStream = NULL;
                if (::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(buffer, FALSE, &pStream) == S_OK) {
                    bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(pStream);
                    pStream->Release();
                    if (bitmap) {
                        if (bitmap->GetLastStatus() == Gdiplus::Ok) {
                            return bitmap;
                        }

                        delete bitmap;
                    }
                }
                ::GlobalUnlock(buffer);
            }
            ::GlobalFree(buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// Based on original method from http://danbystrom.se/2009/01/05/imagegetthumbnailimage-and-beyond/
Gdiplus::Bitmap* GetThumbnail(Gdiplus::Image* bm, int width, int height, Gdiplus::Size* realSize = 0) {
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    if (realSize) {
        realSize->Width = bm->GetWidth();
        realSize->Height = bm->GetHeight();
    }
    Size sz = AdaptProportionalSize(Size(width, height), Size(bm->GetWidth(), bm->GetHeight()));
    Bitmap* res = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);
    Graphics gr(res);

    gr.SetInterpolationMode(Gdiplus::InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic);
    UINT size = bm->GetPropertyItemSize(PropertyTagThumbnailData);
    if (size) {
        // Loading thumbnail from EXIF data (fast)
        enum ThumbCompression { ThumbCompressionJPEG, ThumbCompressionRGB, ThumbCompressionYCbCr, ThumbCompressionUnknown }
            compression = ThumbCompressionJPEG;

        PropertyItem* thumbnailFormatItem = GetPropertyItemFromImage(bm, PropertyTagThumbnailFormat);
        if (thumbnailFormatItem) {
            UINT format = VoidToInt(thumbnailFormatItem->value, thumbnailFormatItem->length);
            if (format == 0) {
                compression = ThumbCompressionRGB;
            } else if (format == 1) {
                compression = ThumbCompressionJPEG;
            } else {
                compression = ThumbCompressionUnknown;
            }
            free(thumbnailFormatItem);
        } else {
            PropertyItem* compressionItem = GetPropertyItemFromImage(bm, PropertyTagThumbnailCompression);
            if (compressionItem) {
                WORD compressionTag = *reinterpret_cast<WORD*>(compressionItem->value);
                if (compressionTag == 1) {
                    compression = ThumbCompressionRGB;
                    PropertyItem* photometricInterpretationItem = GetPropertyItemFromImage(bm, PropertyTagPhotometricInterp);
                    if (photometricInterpretationItem) {
                        WORD photoMetricInterpretationTag = VoidToInt(photometricInterpretationItem->value, photometricInterpretationItem->length);
                        free(photometricInterpretationItem);
                        if (photoMetricInterpretationTag == 6) {
                            compression = ThumbCompressionYCbCr;
                        }
                    }

                } else if (compressionTag == 6) {
                    compression = ThumbCompressionJPEG;
                }

                free(compressionItem);
            }
        }

        int originalThumbWidth = 0, originalThumbHeight = 0;
        if (compression == ThumbCompressionJPEG || compression == ThumbCompressionRGB) {
            PropertyItem* thumbDataItem = GetPropertyItemFromImage(bm, PropertyTagThumbnailData);
            if (thumbDataItem) {
                if (compression == ThumbCompressionJPEG) {
                    Bitmap* src = BitmapFromMemory(reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(thumbDataItem->value), thumbDataItem->length);

                    if (src) {
                        gr.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, sz.Width, sz.Height);
                        delete src;
                        free(thumbDataItem);
                        return res;
                    }
                } else if (compression == ThumbCompressionRGB) {
                    PropertyItem* widthItem = GetPropertyItemFromImage(bm, PropertyTagThumbnailImageWidth);
                    if (widthItem) {
                        originalThumbWidth = VoidToInt(widthItem->value, widthItem->length);
                        free(widthItem);
                    }
                    PropertyItem* heightItem = GetPropertyItemFromImage(bm, PropertyTagThumbnailImageHeight);
                    if (heightItem) {
                        originalThumbHeight = VoidToInt(heightItem->value, heightItem->length);
                        free(heightItem);
                    }
                    if (originalThumbWidth && originalThumbHeight) {
                        BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
                        memset(&bih, 0, sizeof(bih));
                        bih.biSize = sizeof(bih);
                        bih.biWidth = originalThumbWidth;
                        bih.biHeight = -originalThumbHeight;
                        bih.biPlanes = 1;
                        bih.biBitCount = 24;

                        BITMAPINFO bi;
                        memset(&bi, 0, sizeof(bi));
                        bi.bmiHeader = bih;

                        BYTE* data = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(thumbDataItem->value);
                        BYTE temp;
                        // Convert RGB to BGR
                        for (unsigned int offset = 0; offset < thumbDataItem->length; offset += 3) {
                            temp = data[offset];
                            data[offset] = data[offset + 2];
                            data[offset + 2] = temp;
                        }
                        Bitmap src(&bi, thumbDataItem->value);

                        if (src.GetLastStatus() == Ok) {
                            gr.DrawImage(&src, 0, 0, sz.Width, sz.Height);
                            free(thumbDataItem);
                            return res;
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // other type of compression not implemented
                }
                free(thumbDataItem);
            }
        }
    } 
    // Fallback - Load full image and draw it  (slow)
    gr.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0, sz.Width, sz.Height);

    return res;
}

Gdiplus::Bitmap* GetThumbnail(const CString& filename, int width, int height, Gdiplus::Size* realSize) {
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    Image bm(filename);
    if (bm.GetLastStatus() != Ok) {
        return 0;
    }
    return GetThumbnail(&bm, width, height, realSize);
}

Gdiplus::Size AdaptProportionalSize(const Gdiplus::Size& szMax, const Gdiplus::Size& szReal)
{
    int nWidth;
    int nHeight;
    double sMaxRatio;
    double sRealRatio;

    if (szMax.Width < 1 || szMax.Height < 1 || szReal.Width < 1 || szReal.Height < 1)
        return Size();

    sMaxRatio = szMax.Width / static_cast<double>(szMax.Height);
    sRealRatio = szReal.Width / static_cast<double>(szReal.Height);

    if (sMaxRatio < sRealRatio) {
        nWidth = min(szMax.Width, szReal.Width);
        nHeight = static_cast<int>(round(nWidth / sRealRatio));
    } else {
        nHeight = min(szMax.Height, szReal.Height);
        nWidth = static_cast<int>(round(nHeight * sRealRatio));
    }

    return Size(nWidth, nHeight);
}
```